# how can i vectorize to four times nested "for" loop

Tags: r, loops, nested

how can simplify the following r codes.. Because it takes lots of time

```
   I1 <- 0
   m <- 10
    for (k1 in 0:m) {
      for (k2 in 0:m) {
        for (s1 in 0:m) {
          for (s2 in 0:m) {
            I1 <- I1 + C.n(c((k1)/m,(k2)/m),uc) *
              C.n(c((s1)/m,(s2)/m),uc) *
              choose(m,k1) * choose(m,k2) *
              choose(m,s1) * choose(m,s2) *
              beta((k1) + (s1) + 1, 2*m-(k1)-(s1) + 1) *
              beta((k2) + (s2) + 1, 2*m-(k2)-(s2) + 1)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: (1) pre-calculate `choose(m,k1)` (and `,k2`) immediately inside their respective `for` loops, don't re-calculate them every single time in the inner loop. (2) Similarly, pre-calc `beta((k1)...)` immediately inside the `s1` loop. (3) We have no idea what `C.n` does; if it's a 3-hour function, nothing you can do elsewhere will help.

Comment: If you share with us `C.n`, we might be able to advise better.

Comment: If you have access to multiple cores/workers, you could parallelize the inner loop (or squash a couple of layers and parallelize) ... could we have a [mcve]?

Comment: also see https://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-higher-stonger-a-guide-to-speeding-up-r-code-for-busy-people/ ...

Comment: @BenBolker, that's a good article, I like it ... too bad the source site (noamross.net) is down ergo no images.

Answer (score 2):

From my first comment, you might be content with:

```r
I1 <- 0
m <- 10
for (k1 in 0:m) {
  ch_mk1 <- choose(m,k1)
  for (k2 in 0:m) {
    ch_mk2 <- choose(m,k2)
    ch_mk <- ch_mk1 * ch_mk2
    for (s1 in 0:m) {
      ch_ms1 <- choose(m,s1)
      be_k1s1 <- beta((k1) + (s1) + 1, 2*m-(k1)-(s1) + 1)
      for (s2 in 0:m) {
        ch_ms2 <- choose(m,s2)
        be_k2s2 <- beta((k2) + (s2) + 1, 2*m-(k2)-(s2) + 1)
        I1 <- I1 + C.n(c((k1)/m,(k2)/m),uc) *
          C.n(c((s1)/m, (s2)/m), uc) *
          ch_mk * ch_ms1 * ch_ms2 *
          be_k1s1 * be_k2s2        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(I should note that this and all code here is untested, as I don't have your function.)

Though this is still a bit inefficient. Truth be told, I don't think you need `for` loops at all. Many of R's functions really like to do things on a whole vector at a time, and `choose` and `beta` are among them.

Try this, completely removing `for` loops:

```r
eg <- expand.grid(k1 = 0:m, k2 = 0:m, s1 = 0:m, s2 = 0:m)
ch_mk1 <- choose(m, eg$k1)
ch_mk2 <- choose(m, eg$k2)
ch_ms1 <- choose(m, eg$s1)
ch_ms2 <- choose(m, eg$s2)
be_k1s1 <- beta((eg$k1) + (eg$s1) + 1, 2*m-(eg$k1)-(eg$s1) + 1)
be_k2s2 <- beta((eg$k2) + (eg$s2) + 1, 2*m-(eg$k2)-(eg$s2) + 1)
```

Now the big question is `C.n` (and similarly `uc`).

- If it can deal with arguments as vectors, then try this:

  ```r
  I1 <- sum(
    C.n(c((eg$k1)/m, (eg$k2)/m), uc) *
      C.n(c((eg$s1)/m, (eg$s2)/m), uc) *
      ch_mk1 * ch_mk2 * ch_ms1 * ch_ms2 *
      be_k1s1 * be_k2s2
  )
  ```
- If it *cannot* deal with its arguments being vectors (or even if it can but you want to play with this anyway), then try this:

  ```r
  I1 <- sum(
    mapply(C.n, (eg$k1)/m, (eg$k2)/m, uc) *
      mapply(C.n, (eg$s1)/m, (eg$s2)/m, uc) *
      ch_mk1 * ch_mk2 * ch_ms1 * ch_ms2 *
      be_k1s1 * be_k2s2
  )
  ```

  Because this is using just `mapply`, it will parallelize easily if you decide to go the route of multi-processing (e.g., `parallel` package), as @BenBolker suggested in his comment.

Realize that `eg` will grow exponentially, so with `0:10` this means `11^4` or 14,641 rows. If `m` is actually *much* larger, you might run into memory or vector-length limits. In that case, you can go with a hybrid solution that retains the outer two loops (`k1` and `k2`) and uses `expand.grid` on the inner two loops (e.g., `expand.grid(s1 = 0:m, s2 = 0:m)`) vectorizing there. Or the opposite (expanding `k1` and `k2`, looping `s1` and `s2`).